# Separating Clusters after using SLINK in Python/R

Tags: python, r, cluster-analysis

From research, only Single-Linkage Hierarchical Clustering can obtain optimal clusters. This is also know as SLINK. The libraries are published in originally in C++ and now in Python/R.

So far, following the steps in the documentations, I managed to come up with:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

## generating random numbers from 20 to 90, and storing them in a dataframe. This is a 1-dimensional data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20,90,size=(100,1)), columns = list('A'))
df = df.sort_values(by=['A'])
df = df.values
df[:,0].sort()

## getting condensed distance matrix
d = pdist(df_final, metric='euclidean')

## running the SLINK algorithm
Z = linkage(d, 'single')
```

I understand that Z is a 'hierarchical clustering encoded as a linkage matrix' (as written in the documentation), but I am wondering how do I go back to my original data set and distinguish the cluster calculated by this result?

I could achieve clustering result by Scikit-Learn clustering, but I think Scikit-Learn clustering algorithms are not optimal and hence I turned to this SLINK algorithm. Would be much appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

From `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` you get back how clusters are formed with each iteration.

Normally this information is not so useful, so we can look at the clustering first:

```
import scipy as scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
dn =scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)
```

[image]

If we want to get the three clusters, we can do:

```
labels = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(Z,3,'maxclust')
```

If you want to get it by distance between the data points:

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(Z,2,'distance')
```

This gives about the same result as calling for 3 clusters because that's not many ways to cut this example dataset.

If you look the example you have, the next point you can cut it is at height ~ 1.5, which is 16 clusters. So if you try to do scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(Z,5,'maxclust'), you get the same results as for 3 clusters. If you have a more spread dataset, it will work:

```
np.random.seed(111)
df = np.random.normal(0,1,(50,3))

## getting condensed distance matrix
d = pdist(df, metric='euclidean')
Z = linkage(d, 'single')
dn = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram(Z,above_threshold_color='black',color_threshold=1.1)
```

[image]

Then this works:

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster(Z,5,'maxclust')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! However, do you know how to pre-set the number of clusters? For example, I want 5 clusters for this example instead of 3 clusters. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @LucasLe, i edited my answer. It depends on whether your dataset allows you to have 5 clusters.. See my edited answer above

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf. Thanks so much for your answer! However, if you would be so kind to answer one final clarification. Does that mean that the optimal solution can only be obtain at the final cut? I have explored into sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering package, it also offers the method = 'single' for clustering, and there is a option for number of clusters, i.e i can pick any number of clusters to my desire. Am I right to say that method does not guarantee optimality?

Comment: Hmm no problem. Let me try to answer it in parts, yes you can also use sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering, with method='single' and you specify the number of clusters

Comment: I think you have to elaborate more on optimality here.. it's very vague to me.  Setting the cluster to be 5 may not guarantee a solution with 5 clusters, if the data does not allow it. I don't know if this is what you mean by optimality

Comment: Hi, I think I am just wondering the difference between scipy and sklearn clustering techniques. In the above scipy method, the number of intervals are 'fixed' - At different cut there exist a fixed number of clusters - 1,3,16 etc. However, for sklearn clustering, I am able to define any number of clusters - 1, 2, 3,...n. Does that mean either of the clustering method is inferior to the other?

Comment: As for the optimality, I think my main question here is whether SLINK is a deterministic method, or whether sklearn clustering methods are deterministic for that matter.

Comment: Hi @LucasLe, unfortunately I had to go back to my jupyter notebook to think about the question again. So in your example now, I would say the sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering might be let's say misleading. So yes, you can easily cut it some other way to give you 5 clusters

Comment: For me, I would always look at the tree first, before deciding whether the cut or number of clusters makes sense. I think that question is more important than going back and forth about deterministic. It's the same for any clustering algorithm, you will have some uncertainty if the data cannot give you a resolution. Which is why you always check how stable your clusters are, if it is important for downstream processes

Comment: Thank you so much for yr help @StupidWolf!